# LTspice model with encrypted text file

Tags: ltspice

[image]

I want to add an NVHL080N120SC1_3P MOSFET to this circuit
with an encrypted ONSEMI_SiC_MOSFET.txt file. How can I do this?

Comment: On semi have a document the explicitly tells you how to use encrypted files for LTSpice.

Comment: Have a look at that [AN](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND9783-D.PDF) in which all the steps are detailed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This section in [AND9873 - How to use Physical and Scalable Models with SIMetrix, OrCAD and LTSpice](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND9783-D.PDF) should provide you with what you need: -

[image]

You should try figuring it out for micro-cap for a laugh. It wasn't very obvious but I did get there.

Comment: care to share How DID You import encrypted model to micro-cap ? I haven't succeeded.

Comment: Not really an answerable question in comments. Try raising a new formal question.

Comment: Sure thing, did this here:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/676116/123589