# How to convert encrypted PSpice model into LTspice model?

Tags: ltspice, simulation, spice, pspice

I want to simulate the model in this link: https://www.diodes.com/part/view/AL8860Q/#tab-details under the header of the Technical documents and Spice Model on the right-hand side. The problem is that it is encrypted for PSpice simulation. I was wondering if there is a way to decrypt it and use it in the LTspice simulation?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but the AL8806Q (now NRND) seems to be the older predecessor to the AL8860Q and they have an unencrypted model for it:  https://www.diodes.com/part/view/AL8806Q/#tab-details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I was wondering if there is a way to decrypt it and use it in the
> LTspice simulation?*

**Short story**: you can't decrypt it.

**Longer story**: LTspice can use encrypted models (specifically designed for LTspice) just as micro-cap does with it's specifically encrypted model files. You are personally prevented from decrypting them i.e. you cannot have visual access to the raw data because suppliers regard it as their IP.

See [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/642888/20218) on how to do it in LTspice. It refers to an [ON semi document](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND9783-D.PDF) that has the instructions but, the procedure should be the same for any encrypted model from any supplier (within reason).

Comment: Just to add to this, Diodes Inc does make LTspice-specific encrypted models for other parts ([example here](https://www.diodes.com/part/view/AL8862Q/#tab-details)) so it's not beyond their capabilities.  One can try contacting their support to ask if they can provide one specifically for the part in question.