# Method to import encrypted spice models to micro-cap?

Tags: simulation, spice, encryption

I've been struggling to get encrypted spice models to work in micro-cap (v12.2.0.5)

Referring to Andy aka's response, there should be some way to achieve this.
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/642888/123589

For this example I'm struggling with OnSemi's **FDMC86259P** mosfet:
https://www.onsemi.com/products/discrete-power-modules/mosfets/fdmc86259p#technical-documentation

I got the model seemingly working for LTSpice via this resource
https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND9783-D.PDF
but I find micro-cap to be much more intuitive and would love to know how to add encrypted models in there to be able to use any other instance in the future as well.

I haven't found anything reasonable from micro-cap user guide :/ The Component Editor there assumes .lib files only...

Comment: Actually, when I did it I contacted ON semi and they were very helpful on emails helping me through the process. I'm on a different PC at the moment but I'll try and give some help later on this.

Comment: @Andyaka Coming back to this. Hopefully you get some time out of your life to provide some insight what On Semi might of have suggested ?

Comment: I can't remember what I did but ON-semi support were very helpful.